# MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer: How do I use the Volume property?

Tags: vb.net, double, media-player

The Volume property from `MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer` is really confusing me. I googled the definition and found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.volume%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which I think is the right class. It says the `Volume` property is a `Double` that excepts any number between 0 and 1, and it's default is 0.5. However, when I set it to 0.5 or any other number within 0 and 1, it says it does not fall within the expected range.

Here is how it is defined and how I tried to adjust the volume. I have the event as `MouseUp` because I could not get `ValueChanged` or `Scroll` to work properly. Any tips on that would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim Player1 As MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer = New MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer


Private Sub SndMasterSlider_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SndMasterSlider.MouseUp
    Player1.Volume = SndMasterSlider.Value / 100
    Debug.Print(Player1.Volume)
End Sub
```

Comment: Your Trackbar(?) value range may not match the current player.  The default Min/Max is 0-10 while the range for AxWMP is 1-100; so you might not have been changing the volume enough before when it was an AxWMP.  Add a label you your form, and post the current trackbar value to it in the scroll event to see that it is working: `Label13.Text = TrackBar1.Value.ToString` ; it might very well have not been working properly because the Min/Max were too small.

Comment: @Plutonix The range for the trackbar is 0-100. The label for the trackbar shows that it starts at 100. I put a label for the volume of mediaplayer as well and it always showed 0 even when it was playing.

Comment: @Plutonix I just tested something. Whenever I release the trackbar when it is below 50 no error is thrown and goes to the next line printing the volume as 0. Any value above 50 throws the error.

Comment: Make sure it is a trackbar:  If you select it on the form in the designer, then open the Props window (F4), the type name at the top should be `System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar` (yours sort of sounds like a ScrollBar); also make sure you dont have something else somewhere **setting** the value perhaps in an event.  The problem is related to the TrackBar not the player(s)

Comment: Its a `gTrackBar`. From [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35104/gTrackBar-A-Custom-TrackBar-UserControl-VB-NET)

Comment: well either change it to a TrackBar or find the property that makes it snap to something like a Tick.

Comment: @Plutonix I need it as  gTrackBar but I'll try that to see if it fixes the problem. EDIT: Exactly the same thing happens

Comment: @Plutonix The same thing happened, incase you didn't see the edit :). I really need help with this.

Comment: make sure you dont have something else somewhere **setting** the value perhaps in an event. turn on option strict, remove the control and it will flag all the related events and references. remove them then add the TRACKBAR back in.  Make sure the Min and Max are 0-100. yopu could also set a breakpoint in the valuechanged event and look at the call stack to see where(else) it might be getting called from

Comment: @Plutonix It's only being set with the trackbar. There is a mute function which I'm using but it still errors when I don't call that. I also noticed that if I mute it and unmute it, the volume goes slightly lower.

Comment: @Plutonix I put a try/catch around where I set the volume and it is now starting at -600.

Comment: `it still errors`??? you are getting an error?  or it just doesnt work?  I would start a new project, add a TRACKBAR (Min=1, Max=100) and a Label.  Post the value to the label in the Scroll event to verify how it works.  The REAL volume thing underneath is on a [sliding scale that is very odd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930752.aspx) and it sounds like that is coming thru.  I would leave ALL media elements out of it to assure yourself the TrackBar works as advertized, then I would use AxMediaPlayer instead of PresentationCore.

Comment: The trackbar works fine. Does AxWindowsMediaPlayer allow me to create an object without putting in the designer?

Comment: `The trackbar works fine.` that means you have code somewhere messing with the Value where it should not.  I dont understand the (new) question, do you mean the WMP display?  It has a visible property

Comment: Nevermind, I found what I wanted. I don't think the problem is the trackbar, though. It's the Volume property that is acting weird.

Comment: @Plutonix I switched everything to AxWMP but now whenever I try to do anything with the Player1.settings.volume property, I get the error: `System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException' occurred in AxInterop.WMPLib.dll`. (Everything is set up exactly the same as with MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer)